# Calculating area of GeoJSON features within Vector boundaries

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, geojson, area

I am attempting to calculate the area of total building footprints within each census block group within a state.

The building footprints are a .geojson file type and my census blockgroups are a shapefile. So far I have attempted converting the geojson file to a feature class in ArcGIS Pro and then use "Tabulate Area" to find total are in each blockgroup. However, this consistently only outputs 300 or so zones instead of the 3000+ there should be. It also outputs the same total area for each zone.

I have made sure there are no features selected going into the analysis and the coordinate system is appropriate.

Comment: You should not need ArcPy for this.  I'd start with the Summary Statistics and if you get stuck let us know what parameter values you have used.